# ImageJ - ScaleBar in Java

Tags: java, imagej

I have opened an image with this code:

```
this.imp = IJ.openImage(imageFilePath);
imp.show();
```

And now, I need to set the `scaleBar`. I need to set it after `imp.show()` because the user has to draw a line before (and later set the scale). 
But it only works before `imp.show()`. Can I put it after show or something similar? Do I need to invoke a refresh or update method?

Comment: How do you set the scaleBar? Share your code so we can help you.

Comment: If you include new ImageJ(); before you create the ImagePlus, an ImageJ window will be created, and  can use the builtin imagej actions. Including analyze->tools->scale bar.

Comment: Meanwhile, you asked [this question on the image.sc forum](https://forum.image.sc/t/setting-the-scalebar-with-java/20958?u=imagejan) where it is much better suited and already received replies. Please, when cross-posting like this, always link to other places where you asked, so that others don't waste their time with obsolete answers.